# Get asynchronous response of http post request into variable with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm pretty new to Javascript and am trying to wrap my head around the Javascript's asynchronicity concept.

my goal is,

```
responseStr = httpPost(parameters)
// then store responseStr in DB
```

However, the Javascript I can do is,

```
var callback = function(response) {
    var str = '';

    //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });

    //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(str);
        });
    };

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

So I get the http post request's response into the local variable `str`, from above code, but I still cannot imagine how to pass it back to my `httpPost` caller into `responseStr`

Basically, the flow is,

- Within my `httpPost` function, I sent the http request via `http.request`,
- and it returns immediately,
- somehow sometime later, the `callback` function populated the `str` variable bits by bits

but how to pass it back to my `httpPost` caller into `responseStr` when all done so that I can store it away? Thx.

**Summary:**

Thank you all who answered. I enjoy all your sense of humor greatly, upvoting you all.

PS. sharing [a piece of comment I read the other day](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=127), about the Javascript's asynchronicity,

> Today, we will examine four different methods of performing the same task asynchronously, in node.js...:
>
> 1. In parallel, using callback functions
> 2. Sequentially, using callback functions
> 3. In parallel, using promises
> 4. Sequentially, using promises
>
> This will help you decide which to use for your particular situation. It is simply a matter of taste. If you want to know which is the best method -- the absolute best way to go -- is probably to switch to [Golang](http://golang.org/).

:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with what you are trying to do. The first problem being that it is impossible to return a value from a non blocking function that is only available in the future. Don't fret though, once time travel is possible we won't have to worry about this issue ever again :) But until then, where do we go from here? There are a couple of things we can do to get the value.

The first (preferred) solution is to modify your program by simply moving all functionality that uses the value in the place where the value becomes available e.g. the callback. For example, suppose the only functionality that uses value is the function call `do_stuff_with(value)`

```
// original program
var value = get_value('param', callback);
do_stuff_with(value);

// changes to
get_value('param', function (value) {
  do_stuff_with(value);
});
```

Usually the reponse I get from new programmers is *"Oh no! That means I need to change my entire program! Is there anything else we can do. I don't want to change the code. It is perfect and is now a part of my family. You monster!"* I must admit, this is exactly how I felt after being proposed this same solution. There is another solution to this problem you might want to use right away, but it will drastically affect the performance of your program.

The second (terrible, naive, you'll be sorry, don't do it) solution that successfully returns the value from the function call requires you to use a method that supports synchronous functionality. I only see synchronous code in all languages other than javascript, because javascript is single threaded. "*Blasphemy, What the hell does that mean?*" That means the entire javascript program needs to pause the entire process in order to wait for an http request to complete. It is not possible to open an http request without opening a new thread. Is that bad? Hell yea it is. That means the entire user interface will freeze during an http request. That means other tasks scheduled tasks will not be called on time. You know what it's like to play a video game that freezes all the time. It's terrible.

*"But I have no imagination and I really want to write a bad program.*" - Fine, just modify your program to use a method that implements synchronous functionality instead of an asynchronous method that takes a callback. I have no idea where to get this, because I've never needed it.

```
// replace this method
var value = get_str_async_method('param', callback);
console.log(value) // undefined

// use one that is synchronous
// a callback is not needed for this method
var value = get_str_sync_method('param');
console.log(value); // reponse
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward: you can't do that.

This is one of those problems that you have to cope with in JavaScript.  Your callbacks get called after code that got pushed into the event loop was executed, so the surrounding code in your program has already executed synchronously and is long gone.

You should dig into the event loop to get a better feel for this.

As things are arranged currently in your code, nested code is the most straightforward way to handle this. Whatever depends on `str` gets moved to or called from within the callback where `str` gets it's value.

Another way to handle this is to find a package that supports a promise based interface. This allows your asynchronous code to transform from the nested structure asynchronous callbacks force you into and flattens the code.  It can even allow you to do something like what you're trying to do here.

```
const context = {};
doAsync()
  .then(function(result) {
    // Do something with result
    context.str = result;
    return doSomethingElseAsync();
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // No more nesting, more readable, easier to reason about
    context.str2 = result;
    return doAsync3(context.str);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store all data after getting it you can add it to the nested function as down below

```
var callback = function(response) {
var str = '';

//another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    str += chunk;
});

//the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
response.on('end', function() {
    console.log(str);
    responseStr = httpPost(parameters); //this line should be added here 
    });
};
http.request(options, callback).end();
```